# "Единственное" в качестве вводного слова

Tags: грамотная-речь, вводные-слова

Не могу понять, нормально ли такое употребление слова *"единственное"?* Иными словами, будет ли полноценной следующая фраза и правильным обособление этого слова в этом случае?

> Единственное, я не понял, это дефект какой-то или мне просто кажется?

Comment: Артём, добрый вечер! Где лыжи?

Comment: Ахахах, здравствуй, Татьян!)) Все четыре пары лыж стоят в своём углу, как всегда, а фотографию с марафона сменил уже дааавно. Но в фейсбуке по-прежнему она. =) Как дела? Нашёл тебя в контакте, сейчас добавлю)

Comment: Ой, с днём рождения прошедшим забыл поздравить! Здоровья, радостей побольше, удачи во всех делах!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В приведенных ответах уже поднималась **тема вводных слов,** но автор вопроса, как мне думается, не уделил этому достаточного внимания. Я же хочу продолжить именно эту тему.

1. Был принят ответ с довольно жесткой оценкой: **разговорно-сниженный стиль**. Да, пока еще разговорный, но вот правильно ли называть его сниженным?

А что считать тогда стилем хорошим, не сниженным? **Усложнение** синтаксической конструкции, излишнее применение таких **сильных знаков**, как двоеточие, когда вполне достаточно обойтись одним вводным словом?  Ведь именно для ясности и краткости  сказанного и нужны нам вводные слова!

2. **Функция слова «единственное»** ничем не отличается от слова  «главное», только собственный семантический оттенок имеет, а вот тематика одна и та же – оформление речи, авторская оценка сказанного. Возможно применение как тире, так и запятой в обоих случаях.  Да они вообще выглядят просто как близнецы-братья.
3. Да, слово еще не освоилось в языке, но это как бы **начало пути**. Перспективы у него вполне оптимистичные. Уже есть опыт использования наречия «единственно» в этой роли,  хотя этот вариант не получил достаточного распространения.  Да и пользователи языка хорошо понимают  и функцию, и семантику слова. Что же еще-то нужно?

Я думаю, что со временем слово «единственное» будет принято как вводное, опыт его использования уже есть. Особенно надо отметить вариант с тире для обособления, который чаще используется. Остается только заменить тире запятой, когда это необходимо (то есть когда не нужно подчеркивать паузу).

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

Сухотин ни с кем не дружил и даже не поддерживал видимых отношений; **единственное**, он удивительно симпатизировал вахмистру Гусеву… [Сергей Бабаян. Господа офицеры (1994)]

**Единственное** ― я хочу рассказать про человека, которого знал, любил. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

Говоря откровенно, я поступил в лучших традициях русского стукачества: сообщать не то, что есть на самом деле, но то, что от тебя ожидают услышать; **единственное**, я ни на кого не доносил. [Владимир Соловьев (1975-1998)]

Comment: Браво! Рассуждения очень понравились, и примеры хорошие! Перепринял ответ (простите, Александр!). Ваш ответ всё равно очень полезен на тот случай, когда хочешь написать так, чтобы никто придраться не смог. Тот, когда можешь навлечь на себя не очень одобрительный взгляд, а спорить не хочется. Хотя бояться критики не очень правильный путь, но иногда хочется "всем угодить".

Comment: Спасибо, Артем, я вам так благодарна за вашу оценку! Пусть и меня простит Alex_ander  И еще я проголосую за него и за тех, кто уже поднимал в своих ответах тему вводности, не отрицал ее.

Comment: Вы забыли, что ли?) Там только мой голос.

Comment: Не знаю, куда голос  за Alex_ander делся, мистика какая-то, я за него прежде всего проголосовала. Я даже сначала не могла понять, что вы от меня хотите, потом стала проверять голоса, так что исправляюсь. Ну и заодно объясню свою позицию подробнее. Я считаю, что это КОЛЛЕКТИВНЫЙ ответ, так как я смогла учесть мнения всех участников (выгодная позиция, что и говорить, на каком-то году служения на форуме я наконец-то об этом догадалась :). Если бы я отвечала первой, то и ответ, вероятно, выглядел бы иначе. Поэтому я благодарна всем, кто принимал участие в обсуждении.

Comment: Ну а ваш вопрос мне показался ну очень интересным, спасибо :)

Comment: Куда же девался плюсик, я вроде бы видела 2 голоса. Вспомнила, что уже сталкивалась с такой проблемой, но там уже у меня пропал обещанный голос. Версия такая: три быстрых действия за очень короткое время. Система посчитала меня за робота или просто не могла всё корректно зафиксировать, вот и аннулировала одно из событий.

Comment: Интересно, если действительно так и есть, как вы поняли. Спасибо, что хвалите вопрос, мне ооочень приятно!))) У меня он часто возникал, уже давно первый раз им задался.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от предыдущих предложений. Это слово предшествует единственному исключению для того, о чем говорится в предыдущих предложениях.
Меня устраивает эта квартира. Единственное, меня не устраивает вид из окна спальни.
Мне нравится это телефон, хорошая покупка. Единственное, я не понял, это дефект какой-то или мне просто кажется?
Под вводное, предшествующее важному или откровенному, вполне себе подходит.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, это *разговорное* упрощение (напр. сокращение от "*единственное "но"/возражение*), которое на письме выглядит как элемент *сниженного стиля*: опущено существительное или указательное местоимение. На этом месте на законных основаниях могло быть "разве что (я не понял)" или "вот только" (без запятой). Для примера из вопроса безупречен такой вариант:

> Единственное, **чего** я не понял: это дефект какой-то или мне просто
> кажется?
>
> (В общем случае - без встроенного вопроса: *Единственное, чего я не
> понял, /так/ это того-то...*)

Comment: Спасибо большое, Александр!

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, *единственно* при таком употреблении будет восприниматься намного лучше и вполне законно.

Процитирую словарь Остроумовой, Фрамполь.

**ЕДИНСТВЕННО**, частица.

1. Употребляется в функции вводного для выражения
   субъективного отношения к какому-либо факту, при
   желании подчеркнуть его значимость: *Единственно, я
   теперь боюсь, что мне с такси расплатиться не хватит*
   (М. Зощенко); *Единственно, с ними не должно быть мужчин*
   (Е. Гришковец).
2. Невводное, употребляется в функции ограничительно-выделительной частицы (= только), не обособляется: *Этот
   Фирс довольно правдоподобен, но единственно потому, что
   тип старого барского слуги уже сто раз был написан до
   Чехова* (И. Бунин); *Первые минуты обеда посвящены были
   единственно на внимание к произведениям старинной нашей
   кухни, звон тарелок и деятельных ложек возмущал один общее
   безмолвие* (А.Пушкин).

Comment: Спасибо! Как-то мне не кажется, однако, что замена хороша.

Answer (score 0):

**Главное** - вводное слово (Фрамполь).

```
Главное, я не понимаю, с какой стати я должен дать вам денег?
Главное, я не понимаю: если она убежала куда-то, то почему?
Главное, я поняла: нет женщин и мужчин за рулем
```

После **Главное**  может стоять тире по аналогии с подлежащим и сказуемым: `Главное -  я не понял это дефект какой-то или мне просто так кажется`.

**Главное** в нашем конкретном случае при замене на **Главное, что** имеет легкую двусмысленность. Также как и **Единственное** при такой замене будет иметь двусмысленность (то ли это вводное слово, относящееся ко всему предложению, то ли дополнение, относящееся к подлежащему **я**). Для устранения двусмысленности нужно использовать замену на **Единственное - это то, что**:

```
Единственное - это то, что я не понимаю, с какой стати я должен дать вам денег?
Единственное - это то, что я не понимаю: если она убежала куда-то, то почему?
Единственное - это то, что я поняла: нет женщин и мужчин за рулем
```